# Summing values in a vector based on duplicate values in another R

Tags: r, vector, sum, duplicates, unique

Let's say I have two vectors below:

```
r<-c(2,2,4,2,NA,6,8,8,9,NA,2,3)
s<-c(50,57,43,2,NA,11,62,35,9,NA,61,78)
```

What I want to do is to sum all the values in the s vector corresponding to which values are duplicated in the r vector, accouting fro uniqueness. For example, in the r vector, the values 2 and 8 are duplicated at the 1,2,4,11 positions and the 7,8 positions respectively. So I would like to sum s[1], s[2], s[4], and s[11] and place that result on the s[11] position, and sum s[7] and s[8] and put that on the s[8] position, resulting in

```
r<-c(NA,NA,4,NA,NA,6,NA,8,9,NA,2,3)
s<-c(NA,NA,43,NA,NA,11,NA,97,9,NA,170,78)
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` package:

```
DT = data.table(r,s)
DT[, `:=`(r=c(rep(NA, .N-1L), r[1L]), 
          s=c(rep(NA, .N-1L), sum(s))
         ), 
by=r]

> DT
#      r   s
#  1: NA  NA
#  2: NA  NA
#  3:  4  43
#  4: NA  NA
#  5: NA  NA
#  6:  6  11
#  7: NA  NA
#  8:  8  97
#  9:  9   9
# 10: NA  NA
# 11:  2 170
# 12:  3  78
```

We group by column `r`, and for each group, we assign `r` and `s` as shown above, using the `:=` operator, which modifies by reference. `.N` is a special internal variable which holds the number of observations for each group.

When `.N=1`, meaning only one observation, we still calculate `r` and `s`, but it is designed to not modify anything. `sum` and `rep` are very cheap operations and therefore we can afford to calculate even when they're unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I did something with `dplyr`:

```
df<-data.frame(r,s)

library(dplyr)
temp<-df%>% 
  group_by(r)%>% 
  mutate(total=sum(s), last=duplicated(r, fromLast = TRUE), 
          isna=is.na(r), true=(last==TRUE | isna==TRUE)) 

temp<-as.data.frame(unclass(temp))
ifelse(temp$true==FALSE, temp$s<-temp$total, temp$s<-NA)


 [1]  NA  NA  43  NA  NA  11  NA  97   9  NA 170  78
```